# Quicker calculation of double integral in python (like MatLab's integral2)

Tags: python, matlab, scipy, numerical-integration

I'm needing to perform a 2D-integration (one dimension has an infinite bound). In MatLab, I have done it with integral2:

```
int_x = integral2(fun, 0, inf, 0, a, 'abstol', 0, 'reltol', 1e-6);
```

In Python, I've tried scipy's dblquad:

```
int_x = scipy.integrate.dblquad(fun, 0, numpy.inf, lambda x: 0, lambda x: a, epsabs=0, epsrel=1e-6)
```

and have also tried using nested single quads.  Unfortunately, both of the scipy options take ~80x longer than MatLab's.

My question is: is there a different implementation of 2D integrals within Python that might be faster (I've tried "quadpy" without much benefit)?  Alternatively, could I compile MatLab's integral2 function and call it from python without needing the MatLab runtime (and is that even kosher)?

Thanks in advance!
Brad

---

Update:

Turns out that I don't have the "reputation" to post an image of the equation, so please bear with the formatting: fun(N,t) = P(N) N^2 S(N,t), where P(N) is a lognormal probability distribution and S(N,t) is fairly convoluted but is an exponential in its simplest form and a hypergeometric function (truncated series) in its most complex form.  N is integrated from 0 to infinity and t from 0 to pi.

Comment: With integrals there are 2 big time variables, the number of times that `fun` has to be evaluated, and how long it takes to evaluate `fun` each time.  A 'smart' integrator can minimize the number of `fun` calls (that may be important with the `inf` bound`).  But I suspect MATLAB is getting most of its speed from some sort of `jit` compilation of `fun`.  `numpy/scipy` isn't doing anything like that.  But you haven't told us anything about `fun`.

Comment: Interesting, thanks @hpaulj. See above for some further, but still limited, detail on 'fun'. Do you think my best bet would be to consider jit-ting 'fun' (not sure how that works).

Comment: Regarding jit compilation: That can be done in Python with Numba.

Comment: Have you considered to use a non-adaptive integration scheme like the trapezoidal rule (`np.trapz`)? In many application this is faster than adaptive integration. The difference is that you pass function value arrays rather than function handles, which allows to let your function operate on numpy-arrays if that is possible.

Comment: @AmosEgel I haven’t yet considered trapz since the function can have pretty large gradients and would likely need a very fine grid - but that’s definitely worth a try, thanks for the recommendation. I might also see if a 2d gauss-Legendre quadrature saves time ...

Comment: [quadpy](https://github.com/nschloe/quadpy) (a project of mine) might help. It's fully vectorized and in many cases faster than scipy's quadrature.

Comment: Also, please provide the function you want to integrate in terms of Python code. If the function is complicated, simplify it such that it's easy to understand and still shows the error.

Answer (score 0):

First, profile. If the profile tells you that it's evaluations if `fun`, then your best bet is to either `numba.jit` it, or rewrite it in Cython.

Answer (score 0):

I created [quadpy](https://github.com/nschloe/quadpy) once because the the scipy quadrature functions were too slow for me. If you can bring your integrand into one of the respective forms (e.g., the 2D plane with weight function `exp(-x)` or `exp(-x^2)`), you should take a look.